# Search program in multiple table in php mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. I have to search for strings from both tables. I am using `getfulltext` search query in MySQL. How do I search both tables. Both tables are unique and there there is not any reference id between them. My present table query is below :

```
1st tablename= Table_1
2nd tablename= Table_2

("SELECT *FROM Table_1 Where  MATCH(searchkey) AGAINST ('search_string' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ");
```

Comment: Can you post your full table structure please

Comment: running two separate queries is not an option?

Comment: My first table has 2 fields(columns) : id and searckey column and 2nd tables has 2 fields (columns) only id and searcsecondkey.

Comment: @knittl  No this will not be good idea to run 2 separate query.I want to run simultaneously.Thanks

Comment: so what to you want to do exactly?

Comment: you could create a subquery which unions both tables, but then two separate queries might be faster due to indices being used correctly

Answer (score 0):

You say your two tables have IDs? If these IDs aren't related to each other, or you have no other field in the two tables that you can use to reference each other, then you can't `join` them in a single query. Obviously your first table has more than `ID` and `searchkey` if you're looking for a location and city.. You need to provide more information about you're tables and what you're trying to do in order to get more help